# How to "rotate" a function? Or, how to write a function which has a known, rotational symmetry with respect to another function?

Tags: functions, rotations, symmetry

**EDIT 2: I've posted my "real" question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115766/finding-closed-form-eigenvalues-of-a-particular-matrix**

I have posed my question formally in LaTeX here:

[Formalized problem statement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxrfo.png)

But in words, here is my question. Suppose I have two real-valued functions in the real plane, $f$ and $g$. Moreover, I know that $g$ is given exactly by $f$, with its argument rotated by $2\pi/3$. In other words, given knowledge of $f$, we simply rotate the output by $2\pi/3$ to get $g$ everywhere.

How can I formalize this additional information? I used a 2D rotation matrix to find the corresponding argument of $\{x,y\}$ rotated by $2\pi/3$, but I still do not know how to write function $g$ in terms of $f$.

In my full problem, I have a system of nonlinear equations which involve both $f$ and $g$ and I wish to incorporate the rotational symmetry information to reduce the complexity and allow me to determine these functions.

**EDIT:** I began by asking a simpler question than I ultimately want to know, which is how to replace `g` by some function of `f`. Suppose I have a nonlinear system of equations which involve `f` and `g`, how can I eliminate `g` from these equations, given that I essentially "*know*" what `g` is due to it's symmetry with respect to `f`?

Comment: You say “I still do not know how to write function g in terms of f,” yet equation (3) of the formalized problem statement you linked does exactly that. Can you be clearer about what you want to do? (By the way, you can’t find $r$ like in (5), because $f(x,y)$ could be zero for points where $g(x,y)$ is not zero.)

Comment: Would not $r(x,y)$ be given by $g(x,y)/f(x,y) everywhere f(x,y) is not zero, and where f(x,y) is zero, so is g(x,y) and we can simply define r(x,y) to be anything at those places?

Comment: As for my goal, you are right, (3) is technically a prescription for g(x,y), but not a very useful one in my case. I would like to determine $g(x,y)$ in terms of $f(x,y)$ rather than in terms of $f(rotated x,y)$.

Comment: Why is $g$ zero at the same places $f$ is? It is like you are asking this: Let $T(t)$ be the temperature at time $t$, and let $Y(t)=T(t-1)$, the temperature an hour before time $t$. How can I find out the temperature an hour ago if I know the temperature now?” Hint: You can’t.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Perhaps forget about the $r(x,y)$ conjecture on my part. How can I better utilize the symmetry information? Given (3), I essentially *know* the entire function g given f, so how can I replace g by a function of f?

Comment: Since $g(x,y)$ is the value of $f$ at a point *different from $(x,y)$*, I don’t see how you can do any better than (3). If you had a formula for $f$, of course you could simplify the formula, but there is no one way this will simplify for arbitrary functions.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain of that final statement? That doesn't seem right to me. What if I afforded you some additional constraints, like that the functions were continuous, or analytic functions, or strictly positive, etc.?

Comment: To answer your "formal statement", there is generally no suitable $r(x,y)$.  For example, consider a function $f$ which is always zero at some angles but non-zero at others.

Comment: You might be able to do something fancy with analytic functions, but I'm not particularly hopeful that it will be nice.

Comment: I’m not an analyst, but even for analytic functions it seems unlikely. Rotations keep you on the same circle centered at the origin, so this would have to work for analytic/continuous/positive/bounded/whatever real-valued functions defined on the unit circle. I don’t see how this can work well for anything but constant functions or, say, the set of translations of one given/known non-constant function. Again, it’s the “What was the temperature an hour ago?” question. (Write the temperatures on the boundary of a clock, i.e., a circle.)

Answer (score 1):

You wish to find

$$
g(x, y) = f(x, y)\  \text{rotated by} \ 2\pi/3
$$

To do this, let us assume for the moment that there is some matrix $R$ that  rotates the axis by $2 \pi / 3$ for us. In that case, $g(x, y)$ will be given be $f(R^{-1} \cdot (x, y))$. This is because, the value at $g$ is $2\pi/3$ from the value of $f$. Hence, we need to rotate *backwards* by the same amount (which is why we take $R^{-1}$).

Let the rotation matrix be $R$. Then

$$
g(x, y) = f(R^{-1} \cdot(x, y)^T)
$$
There is a $(x, y)^T$ since I'm treating $(x, y)$ as a column vector rather than a row vector.

It is well known that a rotation matrix which rotates a column vector by an angle $\theta$ is

$$
R = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}
$$

In your case, substitute $\theta = 2\pi/3$ for the right answer.

Comment: According to the OP’s problem statement, the range of $f(x,y)$ is the reals, so how does $g(x, y) = R\cdot f(x, y)$  work?

Comment: But $f(x,y)$ is not a 1x2 vector that can be acted on by $R$, it is simply a real-valued function. Something like $g(x,y)=f(R\cdot(x,y))$ holds, but not what you wrote, no?

Comment: Ah, right. It should be $f(R^-1 (x, y))$ in that case. Hang on, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output rotated by a matrix $R$, then $g(\vec{x}) = f(R^{-1}\vec{x})$ where $R^{-1}$ is just the inverse rotation.

Comment: Actually the way I've written it it would simply be $g(\vec{x}) = f(R \cdot \vec{x})$, but this is essentially my starting point. How do I actually use that information to determine g(x)?

Comment: $g(x,y)$ is fully determined. If you are hoping to find a way of determining the value of $g(a,b)$ solely from the value of $f(a,b)$, you are out of luck, because $g(a,b)$ is the value of $f$ at a point different from $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Steve You would think.  And would be wrong. :-)  To rotate the output one way, you have to rotate the input the other.  You can see this easily if you rotating the output of $f(x, y) = x$ by 90 degrees counter-clockwise.  By inspection the function we want is obviously $g(x, y) = y$.  But if you rotate the input 90 degrees counter-clockwise, the function you get is $-y$ - the exact opposite of what you want!  (This is connected to the fact that when you turn one way, the whole world looks like it is turning the other.)

Comment: As for how you use it, you take any vector $\vec{x}$, multiply it by the rotation matrix, then apply the function $f$.